# SQL: Glue two independent tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union

I have two independent tables:

```
Emp: id, name, bossid
Data: d_id, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5
```

I would like to create a new table in **postgreSQL**:

```
Goal: id, name, bossid, d_id, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5
```

**What query would be suitable?**

EDIT
Result table

```
id   |   name   | bossid   | d_id   |   d1   |   d2    |   d3 ...   
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     |          |          |        |        |         |
```

EDIT2
The `Goal` table will have all the records from `Emp` and the same number of records form `Data`. So its like `LEFT JOIN` but I do not have the `ON` condition as the tables are not related.

Comment: you can use `join` and `create table as select`

Comment: do you want to create a new table, or maybe a materialized view?

Comment: exists a relation between these tables?

Comment: No relation between tables.
I want to create a new table that will have all of the columns from `Emp` and `Data` as its own columns.

Comment: If the two tables are *not related*, you still need to define *which* row from `Data` shall be appended. If nothing else, say "an arbitrary row" - which is different from "a random row" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE result AS
SELECT e.*, d.*
FROM  emp e
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 1) d ON TRUE
```

This does exactly what you ask for.
For lack of definition I took the *cheapest* solution, picking exactly one arbitrary row from `Data` to append to every row from `Emp`.

The resulting table has all rows from `Emp`, regardless of the number of rows in `Data`, which can even be empty.

#### Append one DISTINCT arbitrary row from the secondary table:

```
CREATE TABLE result AS
SELECT id, name, bossid, d_id, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5
FROM        (SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM emp) e
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM data) d USING (rn)
```

Same as above, but an arbitrary distinct row from `Data` is appended. Again, works for 0-n rows in `Data`.

Effect for *this* number of rows in `Data`:

- 0 rows in `Data`: All rows represented in result; all rows have NULL in columns from `Data`.
- Fewer than in `Emp`: All rows represented in result; excess rows from `Emp` have NULL in columns from `Data`.
- Equal number of rows: All rows represented in result; no additional NULL values.
- More than in `Emp`: Arbitrary excess rows from `Data` are **lost**; no additional NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cross join, but this might have undesired results depending on your needs.

```
CREATE TABLE Goal AS
    SELECT *
    FROM Emp CROSS JOIN Data
```

Comment: you can simplify your query replacing all columns by `*` but this is ok

Comment: Well I want to avoid repetitions like it takes place in cathesian product.

Comment: @Szczepan for avoiding repetitions you must have a parent relationship between your tables, otherwise this is impossible

Comment: @Aramillo Ohh how would such query look like then if we assume the parent relationship?

Comment: @Szczepan if you have a relationship, you would join both tables using `inner join`, and your problem would be resolved

Comment: @Aramillo So this eg would be correnct?:
`CREATE TABLE empfull AS 
SELECT e.e_id, e.e_name, e.e_bossid, w.w_id, w.w_s1, w.w_s2, w.w_s3, w.w_s4, w.w_s5
FROM empbase e
LEFT JOIN Data w
ON e.e_id=d.w_id
;`

Comment: @Szczepan somthing like that, but check that left join inserts null values in columns where condition not matches, instead of `left join` i suggest `inner join`, but it depends of your situation of course

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. If you sum up all as ansewer (not comment) I can mark it as ansewer.